# 2gis карта, позиция просмотра карты

Tags: карты, 2gis-api

`center` - Начальный географический центр карты.
Все работает как надо, центрирует постоянно по центру карты, но как мне сделать центрирование так, чтобы позиция не смещалась в центр, а оставалась на том, где остановились?

Использования метода `DG.latLngBounds` результатов не принесло, он хоть и работает, но не так.
Мне нужно оставаться на позиции на которой остановились.
В 2GIS-API, не могу найти нужную информацию, все не то, и все скачет туда-сюда, а не центрирует на позиции, на которой остановились.

Кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой? И как ее решить, пожалуйста подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верное решение

```
chart.on('moveend', function () {
    var pos = this.getCenter();
    //...
});
```

**UPD:**
Перестали использовать 2гис. Теперь google. Он лучше. В нем отражены все территории и прорисовка есть, а 2гис платный стал в поиске, и к тому-же в нем нет многих координат, а также многих функций...